# AutoIt wait for Chrome to load

Tags: autoit

Using AutoIt, how can I determine when a chrome browser has finished loading?  Any working examples are highly appreciated. I read there was a way with checking pixel colors, but that doesn't seem very efficacious.

Answer (score 1):

If you are opening Chrome using AutoIt and immediately navigating to a specific web page everytime, then one option is to run a loop checking for particular content on the page (such as copyright text in the footer).

A rough skeleton of the code might be:

```
Opt('WinTitleMatchMode', 2) ;ensure partial window title matches on and WinActivate, WinExists, WinWait, WinWaitActive, WinKill commands

; code to load chrome via Run dialog goes here
WinWaitActive("Chrome")
sleep(500)
send("^a") ;select all on the browser's active tab
sleep(250)
send("^c") ;copy it into the clipboard
sleep(250)
Local $webPageContents = ClipGet()
; if statement or while loop to check for the existence of some string of content on the webpage
```

Unfortunately, this won't actually determine if the page has returned with an http 200 status response and all assets/images are fully loaded, but might suffice.

---

If you absolutely need to know that the page has fully loaded, you'd probably want to script opening the Web Inspector/Dev Tools and navigating to the Network panel, reading the Network Requests data repeatedly every couple seconds for until the previous state and current state match to determine the page has finished loading all its assets.

[image]

Comment: I might be a bit naive, but shouldn't checking for the [reload button](https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-ae92b32bf2255fc758cf0ea8e4b76b18-c) (with PixelSearch or ImageSearch) be ok? (it's a cross to stop loading and becomes the reload button, once the site is fully loaded.)

Comment: Pixelsearch could also work- it would require mapping the location of the browser window in terms of the desktop and, in turn mapping the refresh button's position.

Comment: Imagesearch would also require mapping the browser window's location in terms of the desktop.

Comment: I agree - definitively not a clean way (dependent on Window position, probably screen resolution too), but I thought I'd share my 5 cent, as OP mentioned Pixelsearch. (should have commented on the question instead of the answer)